# Problem with scrbook and scrpage2 when defining a new page style

Tags: header-footer, scrbook, scrpage2

I'm writing a cumulative dissertation in `scrbook` in which I have to embed multiple publications in PDF. This works all right with `includepdf`, but I thought it would be nice to keep the header and/or footer information in place, to make it easier for the readers to figure out where they are. I used the standard "headings" page style to get the chapter/section information in the header and the page number centered in the footer. This is a problem  for the PDF, though, because the page number is printer on top of the publication's footer, rendering both unreadable. Therefore, I tried to get both chapter title and page number into the header. I ended up defining my own style, and it works nicely, but for some reason there is suddenly a page number in the footer of the first page in a new chapter - which normally should be plain. Can you tell me how that happened?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, BCOR=15mm, 11pt, numbers=noenddot, DIV=12]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

% changing headers and footers
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}
\defpagestyle{mystyle}{%
    (0pt, 0pt)
    {\headmark\hfill\pagemark}
    {\pagemark\hfill\headmark}
    {\pagemark\hfill\headmark}
    (\textwidth, 0.5pt)
}{%
    {\hfill}{\hfill}{\hfill}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chapter pages use pagestyle `plain` as default. So you have to change this pagestyle too. Additionally you can use the predefined style `scrheadings`.

```
\documentclass[BCOR=15mm, numbers=noenddot, DIV=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% changing headers and footers
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot% removes the default content of header and footer
\setheadsepline{.5pt}
\ohead{\headmark}
\ihead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If there should be no page number on the chapter page remove the optional argument of `\ihead`.

---

Note that `scrpage2` is outdated. I would recommend to use its successor `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass[BCOR=15mm, numbers=noenddot, DIV=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% changing headers and footers
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=.5pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles% removes the default content of header and footer
\ohead{\headmark}
\ihead*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If there should be no page number on the chapter page use `\ihead{\pagemark}` instead the starred version.

Comment: Thank you, that works! I had tried an approach with `scrheadings` as well, with the same problem - that must have been the optional argument I didn't understand.